# Amazon Lex Name Variations

Tags: amazon-lex

I have a Lex Bot that needs to handle variations on spelling of names. If someone says "John" I would like to be able to return a list of spelling options such as John, Jon, Jonathan. I then plan to use a Lambda to do some database look ups to determine what our system has stored as the name. It would be nice, if the name would allow for variations, such as if they say "Dick", it would map Dick, Richard, Rich.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really within the realm of Lex to perform the task you're describing. However, you could use Lex to capture the name and through Lambda integration with Lex, use custom code to decipher the input and derive the list of spelling variations.

[Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Lex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-lex.html)